# How to validate swagger security flow with oauth2 token?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi

When an API designed with the securityDefinition as below, it is not clear how the validation should be done.

Lets say there's an API resource with following oauth2_client_credentials security flow is configured. Then if that API resources invoked with a Oauth2 token which was taken from password grant should be rejected by the gateway isn't it?

If so, gateway need to know how that token has taken either from password grant or client_credential grant. In order to know that we have Oauth2 introspection API, but that does not provide the information on the grant type.

How this validation can be done?
What is the recommended approach?

Please advice.

```
securityDefinitions:
  oauth2_authorization_code:
    type: oauth2
    flow: accessCode
    tokenUrl: 'https://authserver.example/token'
    authorizationUrl: 'https://authserver.example/authorization'
    scopes:
      accounts: read accounts
  oauth2_client_credentials:
    type: oauth2
    flow: application
    tokenUrl: 'https://authserver.example/token'
    scopes:
      accounts: read accounts
```

Comment: Shouldn't this (restricting the set of allowed flows) be the responsibility of your authorization server rather than your API gateway?

Comment: Can you please explain bit more? How it can be a responsibility of authorization server? How it will work?

Comment: I mean that your API shouldn't care about how the access token was obtained. The authorization server should have all the necessary information about clients and resources to be able to allow or deny certain flows. It simply shouldn't issue tokens for flows that are not allowed.